# How to create a modal notification when the power off button clicked during plugged charger?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, power-management, battery, notification

I have a problem when I want to create a modal notification when the power off button or keyboard key is pressed during plugged charger.

**The rules;**

1. When button "Power Off" is clicked / Keyboard "Power Off" is pressed, then;
2. Check the charger is plugged or not, when the charger is plugged, then;
3. Show to "Confirmation Modal" with message *"Please unplug your charger before shutting down."* *(In this case, the "Power Off" modal doesn't show up yet before it confirmed)*.
4. When the User confirmed, then show the "Power Off" modal as previous view.

Does anyone know how to custom it?

[image: custom notif]

[image: custom modal]

Comment: You may need to install a gnome shell extension to do this customization.

Comment: @AkibAzmain can you show me how to do that?

Comment: If you know how to install gnome shell extensions, then just search for an extension which can do the job for you. If you don't know, then you have learn how to install a gnome shell extension.

Comment: @AkibAzmain what the name of it extension?

Comment: I don't know about any extension till now which can do it. There should be one in the internet. If you know JavaScript, you can also make your own.